# The getter of <f:passThroughAttributes value> is not called in the RENDER RESPONSE phase for ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, passthrough-attributes

I am having the following problem: the method binding for the tag `<f:passThroughAttributes>` used to populate the component with passthrough attributes is not called for AJAX Request.

```
<f:ajax execute="@this otherComponent"
        listener="#{myController.doSomething}"
        render="otherComponent">
   <h:inputText id="myComponent" value="#{myModel.value1}">
      <f:passThroughAttributes value="#{myController.getAttributesFor("myComponent")}" />
   </h:inputText>
</f:ajax>

<h:inputText id="otherComponent" value="#{myModel.value2}"></h:inputText>
```

Why isn't it called?

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry for the confusion. Next time i will try to make it better.    the original code is to long to put it here;) The idea behind what i am trying to do is the same as what i am showing here. i removed the ":" because it was my mistake. Thanks for that.

I also updated the code. Sorry for the confusion

During the initial page load or other postbacks the getter methods of the <f:passThroughAttributes> are called.

Answer (score 2):

You never told `<f:ajax>` to render the current input component as well. Add `@this` to the `render` attribute.

```
<f:ajax ... render="@this otherComponent">
```

This must call the getter method and produce the desired HTML output. However, this will cause a new problem: passthrough attributes are ignored by Mojarra's ajax update script, see also line 1419 and forth of `jsf.js` of Mojarra 2.2.4 when project stage is set to `Development` (didn't check MyFaces on this one):

```
1419                } else if (d.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
1420                    // special case handling for 'input' elements
1421                    // in order to not lose focus when updating,
1422                    // input elements need to be added in place.
1423                    parserElement = document.createElement('div');
1424                    parserElement.innerHTML = html;
1425                    newElement = parserElement.firstChild;
1426
1427                    cloneAttributes(d, newElement);
1428                    deleteNode(parserElement);
1429                }
```

So in order to keep input's focus (e.g. when triggered during `keydown`), it's not replacing the entire input element with the ajax-rendered one, but only cloning its attributes. However, the `cloneAttributes()` function only clones **predefined** HTML attributes such as `id`, `class`, etc, not custom ones and for sure not passthrough ones. To work around this, wrap the input element in a span and ajax-udpate it instead:

```
<h:panelGroup id="foo">
    <h:inputText id="myComponent" value="#{myModel.value1}">
        <f:passThroughAttributes value="#{myController.getAttributesFor("myComponent")}" />
        <f:ajax execute="@this otherComponent" 
                listener="#{myController.doSomething}" 
                render="foo otherComponent" />
   </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Solves that problem but there remains one question. ```f:passThroughAttributes``` as TagHandler is executed in ```RESTORE_VIEW-Phase``` while the Ajax-Listener is executed in ```INVOKE_APPLICATION-Phase```. So it seems that it’s not possible to get dynamic passThroughAttributes dependent on some Ajax-executed-businesslogic. Any ideas? Shall I open another question?

Comment: The tag is indeed resolved during view build time, but the attribute values are resovled during view render time, so I don't understand what problem you're currently facing. Did you really apply the answer as to actually updating the component with the new attributes manipulated by ajax action?

Comment: If I use the example above and ```myController.doSomething``` sets ```myModel.value1``` to the current time and ```myController.getAttributesFor``` adds this value as passThroughAttribute the value and the passThroughAttribute differ. The passThroughAttribute holds the value from one call before because this value was set in ```RESTORE_VIEW-Phase```.

Comment: As said, it works for me. Attribute values are evaluated during view render time. Did you really update the input component's parent or at least `@form` as indicated in bottom of the answer?

Comment: I did and changed to execute ```@form``` but same problem. I also changed to Mojarra 2.2.4 (was working with 2.2.2 before) but still same problem.  I committed a [simple example on github](https://github.com/lefloh/jsf-dynamic-passthrough) if you want to take a look.